# Algorithm for generating abstract keys in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have an array with each letter

```
    alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

    input ="cg?"
```

Then i'm creating sub-keys

```
    sub_keys = (2..letters.length).flat_map do |n|
      letters.combination(n).map(&:join).map{|n| n = n.length.to_s + n.chars.sort.join } 
    end.uniq
```

Which gives me

```
    sub_keys = ["2?c, 2?g, 2cg, 3cg?"]
```

Now i want to transform my sub_keys to get expected output which is

```
    keys = [2ac, 2bc, 2cc, 2c, 2ag, 2bg, 2cg, 2dg, 2eg, 2fg, 2gg, 2g, 3acg, 3bcg, 3ccg, 3cdg, 3ceg, 3cfg, 3cgg, 3cg]
```

As you can see some keys like: 2c, 2g, 3cg stand out from the rest. In my code 2c acts as 2cd, 2ce, 2cf etc.. This is the output i want and my code for it is here:

```
    keys_with_blanks = sub_keys.select{ |k| k.include? "?" }.map{ |k| k.gsub("?","") }
    keys = keys_with_blanks.map do |k| 
      current_letters = choose_letters(all_letters, k)
      k = current_letters.map{ |l| l.gsub(l,l+k) } 
    end.flatten.map{ |k| k.chars.sort.join }.uniq
    keys += keys_with_blanks
```

For making less keys as the input grows, i decided to choose only the letters i need from the alphabet in each iteration instead of all of them, hence the line `current_letters = choose_letters(all_letters, k)`
choose_letters:

```
    def choose_letters(letters, key)
      letters = letters.select{ |l| l <= key.chars.last }
    end
```

Let's say if i have a key `key = "2c"` then choose_letters will return `["a","b","c"]`

This way i only make the keys i need. Up to about 13 character input its quite fast. The problem start when input is 14 or 15 characters long. Then it takes 3 or 4 seconds to make all the keys.

**THIS IS THE SLOW PART**

```
     keys = keys_with_blanks.map do |k| 
       current_letters = choose_letters(all_letters, k)
       k = current_letters.map{ |l| l.gsub(l,l+k) } 
     end.flatten.map{ |k| k.chars.sort.join }.uniq
```

It takes about 3-4 seconds for `input = "abcdefghijklmn?"`

**QUESTION**

How can the code be refactored to generate keys faster? My latest upgrade was to impletent `choose_letters` method, so keys like "2cd", "2ce", "2cf" and so on wouldn't generate, because they work exactly like "2c". Now it generates only the keys i need, so it's a little faster, but still.. Can it be faster?

Comment: What's your goal? Since you're working with combinations, it is expected that it will be slow. The number of keys grows exponentially.

Comment: I'm making Scrabble word finder. For this reason i implemented a Trie in which words are stored like this: ex. word "slow" in my Trie would be "4loswslow" - in consists of word length, letters used in alphabetical order + word itself. When enter input = "abcdefghijklmno" - its generates keys and looks for their children in my Trie. It is very fast. Now i want to implement possibility of using blank Tile. hence the "?". I though maybe my bad practices led to generating being so slow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Your question should be what you wrote in this comment. With your current question, people might help you find a solution which might not be needed at all.

Comment: I guess it might seem too abstract and chaotic. I will repost it if noone answers.

Comment: It's difficult to get readers to devote the time needed to prepare answers for questions like this one. The main problem is that quite a bit of time is needed just to understand the question.